# Grammar question, problem with FIRST

Tags: grammar

Consider following grammar:

```
A → BC
B → Ba | epsilon
C → bD | epsilon
D → …
…
```

The problem here is that rule `B` can derive `epsilon` and left-recursive as well.

In order to find `FIRST(A)` I am searching `FIRST(B)`.
But I stuck on `FIRST(B)`, because it is left-recursive.

So what is `FIRST(B)`?  And `FIRST(A)`?
My version is:

```
FIRST(B) → {a, epsilon}
FIRST(A) → {a, b, epsilon}
```

Is that correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you have it right. A left-recursion does not contribute to FIRST, because when `Ba` is matched for `B`, the `B` in `Ba` must start with something that `B` can start with - because it's a `B`, after all. :)

You could also instead factor out the left-recursion first.